# How to solve this recurrence $2T(n/2)+c*n\log n$ for $n\geq 1$

Tags: notation, induction, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Community,

currently I am trying to solve the following recurrence by substitution:

$$
T(n)= \begin{cases} c & \text{if n=1} \\
2T(\frac{n}{2})+c*n\,\log\,n & \text{if n>1} \end{cases}
$$

My progress:

Guessing the solution: $$ n\ \log\ n $$

To show: $$ T(n) \leq c*n\ \log\ n $$

Proof by Induction:

$$ T(1)= c\leq c*1\ \log\ 1= c \leq c*0 $$
$$ T(2)= 2(\frac{2}{2})+c*2\ \log\ 2 = 2+c*2 \leq c*2 $$

The problem is that there is not existing an c>0 which makes this inequality true, because the left equation will always be larger.

I think I did a mistake.
Can somebody show me where I did a mistake?

sincerely,
M.Hisoka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$T(n)
=2T(n/2)+c*n\log n
$,
put $n = 2^m$
to get
$T(2^m)
=2T(2^{m-1})+c*m2^m
$,
with maybe a different $c$
depending on the
base of logs.

Dividing by $2^m$,
this becomes
$\dfrac{T(2^m)}{2^m}
=\dfrac{T(2^{m-1})}{2^{m-1}}+c*m
$.

Letting
$U(m)
=\dfrac{T(2^m)}{2^m}
$,
this becomes
$U(m)
=U(m-1)+cm
$
for which the solution is
$U(m)
=cm(m-1)/2+U(0)
$.

Working backwards,
$\dfrac{T(2^m)}{2^m}
=cm(m-1)/2+U(0)
$,
so
$T(2^m)
=2^m(cm(m-1)/2+U(0))
$.

Replacing $m$ by $\lg n$,
this becomes
$T(n)
=n(c\lg^2(n)+O(1))
$.

Therefore the exact order of $T(n)$
is $\Theta(n \ln^2(n))$.

Whenever you have
$T(n)
=aT(n/b)+f(n)$,
replacing $n$ by $b^m$
will get this
type of solution.

If the recurrence is
$T(n)
=aT(n^{1/b})+f(n)
$
(the usual case is
$b = 2$),
the substitution
that converts it to
a linear recurrence is
$n = b^{b^m}$.

Comment: Thank you, it makes now sense.

Answer (score 0):

What if $n$ is odd? What does $T(n/2)$ mean in this case?

Please excuse me for this false answer, but I can't comment.